# Every time $x$ is doubled y decreases by a factor of $2.5$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-equations

It's been too long since I've had to do this kind of math, so I'm hoping to get some help.  I need to figure out the $x$ to $y$ relationship so that I can properly calculate the capacity of some filters.  On the left side of the equation I have flow rate and on the right side I have the amount of water that can be treated at that flow rate.  Every time the flow is doubled the amount that can be treated goes down by a factor of $2.5$.  The opposite is also true, every time the flow is halved the amount goes up by a factor of $2.5$.

Here's the data I'm working with: $2.5$ gpm = $25000$ gallons and $5$ gpm = $10000$ gallons

How can I solve the amount for the flow rate being $1$ gpm, or $7$ gpm, etc.

Thanks

Comment: By "goes up by" do you mean that it increases by *adding* 2.5, or by *multiplying* 2.5?  Based on your data I assume you mean the latter.

Comment: That's correct it's the latter, it's multiplied by 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Relationships like this can be modeled by a *power function* of the form
$y = ax^r$
where $a$ and $r$ are constants.  In particular, substituting $x=2.5,y=25000$ we have
$$25000=a(2.5)^r$$
and substituting $x=5,y=10000$ we have
$$10000=a5^r$$
If we divide the first equation by the second, we have
$$2.5=(0.5)^r$$
which has the solution $r=\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5} \approx -1.322$.  Back-substituting this into the first equation, we have
$$25000 = a (2.5)^{-1.322}$$
which has the solution $a \approx 83949$.  Putting this all together, we have
$$y = 83949x^{-1.322}$$
as a reasonable model for your data.  (Plug in $x=2.5$, $x=5$, and $x=10$ to see what the corresponding values of $y$ are.)

Now just plug in any value of $x$ you want to see what the corresponding value of $y$ is.

If you want a more exact formula (one that doesn't rely on decimal approximations) you can proceed as follows:  Back-substitute the exact value $r=\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5}$ into the first equation to get
$$25000 = a (2.5)^{\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5}}$$
the solution of which is
$$a=25000(2.5)^{-\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5}}$$
so that the final equation is
$$y=25000(2.5)^{-\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5}} x^{\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5}}$$ which can be simplified to
$$y=25000\left(\frac{x}{2.5}\right)^{\frac{\log 2.5}{\log 0.5}}$$